# Chrome Extension Options from a content script

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I'm porting my Firefox Extension to Chrome and the lack of a synchronous preferences service is making life fun.

I have an options page for my users and I'm using the approach from here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options. I'll be running a content script to get data from the page and using sendMessage to send/receive callbacks to a background script.

The content script needs access to my Extension Options. It needs these before it does it's processing. Of course the Storage API is Asynchronous. I've tried cheating with Stratify.js to force the Storage API to behave Synchronously, but that's ugly as heck.

That leaves me writing code like this:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(defaultPrefs, function(myPrefs) {

     //Do all my webpage processing here, 
     //basically writing my entire Extension inside
     // this call to chrome.storage.sync.get()
}
```

I've seen this question asked before with a few solutions, but they mostly use localStorage, which won't work since I want to use my preferences from here.

This just feels wrong, but if I'm going to use the Storage Sync API for my Extension preferences then I'm kinda stuck. The localStorage solutions I've used mostly involve calls to sendMessage and leave me stuck in the same sort of callback pattern. I'm I missing something?

Comment: So, what's the problem with it being asynchronous?

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing any thing. The Google API is callback driven as it follow the Javascript philosophy. And you should accept it to become a good javascript developer.

A reason of the asynchronous mode for Sync Storage is the latency of the network and the possibly long time to send/receive the data from the synced storage. Javascript VM is mono-thread so if the call to the storage is synchronous and take some times, the user interface will freeze waiting for the response. This is not acceptable for the user experience. The only way to avoid this behavior is to use callbacks. you give the function that you want to execute when the request is finished.

It's not the better pattern ever made but it does the job. But it has a limitation : the Callback Hell. You can try to manage it with Promises and defining simple and short functions that only do one atomic action. Having a Functional Programming approach can help to do this.

An other way to avoid it is to create an object that will automatically synchronize himself with the storage. It allow you to use it fully synchronously but it's more difficult to handle possible errors. I have made one [here](https://github.com/EmrysMyrddin/Chrome-Sync-Storage). It lacks of error handling and can largely be improved but you can get the idea.

I will try to improve this later but I lack time...

Comment: Thanks :). It's not really callback hell that bothers me. My code isn't that complex in this case. It's just that my main program logic is going to be driven from a callback that exists just to get a few settings. That seems like it's going to perform really badly either way and defeat the purpose of the asynchronous callback.

Comment: Yes I had the same feeling :-) It's why I have made this litle object. It's really cool to use